# How to set Padding Dynamically in Android

Tags: android, padding

I have a situation where I need to **set padding to a textview** so as to place it **inside of a imageview.** I have alomost achieved it dynamically by setting the padding but I strongly believe that what I have done is a really bad practice to follow. Please look at the following code :

**CODE :**

```
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int padding_5dp = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
        int padding_20dp = (int) (20 * scale + 0.5f);
        int padding_50dp = (int) (50 * scale + 0.5f);

        if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
                || (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            System.out.println("It is inside the large screen");
            // txtTitle.setLayoutParams(new
            // LayoutParams(padding_50dp,padding_50dp));
            txtTitle.setPadding(padding_20dp, padding_5dp, padding_5dp,
                    padding_5dp);

        }

        if (Academics_Activity.getRotation(getContext()).equalsIgnoreCase(
                "landscape")
                || Academics_Activity.getRotation(getContext())
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("reverse landscape")) {
            System.out.println("Landscape it is");
            if (position == 0) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(310, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(280, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(320, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(250, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(350, 40, 0, 0);
            }
        } else {

            if (position == 0) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(150, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(130, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(160, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(100, 40, 0, 0);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                txtTitle.setPadding(180, 40, 0, 0);
            }

        }
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

Here I have a listview with images and textview as its repeating items. And the sad part is that I have different images which does not accept the text to fit properly. An accurate idea will evolve if you see the screen shots  below :

[image: Screen Shot of Mobile (4 inch screen)]

The above image is the one that was taken in a **Mobile (4 inch)**, it works well in mobiles that has 4 inch and above but the view is distorted in mobiles below 4 inch screens.

[image: Screen Shot of Tab(10 inch screen)]

The above image was taken from a **tab with 10 inch** screen size. I have made use of following code for tab :

```
            final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int padding_5dp = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
            int padding_20dp = (int) (20 * scale + 0.5f);
            int padding_50dp = (int) (50 * scale + 0.5f);

            if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
                    || (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                System.out.println("It is inside the large screen");
                txtTitle.setPadding(padding_20dp, padding_5dp, padding_5dp,
                        padding_5dp);

            }
```

When I use the same technique in a mobile phone, the view is distorted.

**Question :**

Is there a way where I can set the padding dynamically depending upon the screen size or so ? I know that this is a special case where I need to set the padding depending upon the imageview but is there a way to achieve this programmatically (I mean, is there a way where I dont specify the padding depending upon each position cause that is just tiresome !!!) ?

Thanks y'all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't solve it dynamically. It is problem of markup runtime framework. I suggest you to split your item of list into 2 layers:

1. TextView with nine patch background
2. ImageView with appropriate icon

[image]

In xml it could look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout

        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/nine_patch_background"
            android:text="Your title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And as result everything will work at any device with different screens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put your dimensions in a dimens.xml file. Then, acces it from your code, using R.dimen.your_dimen_id.

Then you'll have to put a dimen file in "values" directory, in "values-sw600dp" directory and in "values-sw720dp-land" directory. If they don't exist yet, just create them in the "res" directory.

Then, you'll just have to put the dimensions you want in each case. It'll be something like that in each xml file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="your_margin">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `LinearLayout` and set `sumweight` for parent (Linearlayout) And `weight` for childern